# Using a value in React returned from a function in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use a value returned from a Typescript function and accordingly render a page in React. The two specific values I am trying to retrieve as returned values from a function are the output of `getIcon()` and `getSpaces()`

This is where I try to render the page

```
{
        key: 'column3',
        name: 'Column3',
        onRender: (item: IDetailsListModuleItem) => {
            var icon = this.getIcon(item.sizeDifference);
            console.log(icon);
            return <span>{item.sizeDifference} {this.generateSpace(5)} <img src={this.getIcon(item.sizeDifference)} alt="Increase" /></span>;
        },
    },
```

The functions I use are defined below

```
public generateSpace(numSpaces: number){
  var allSpace = '';
  var spaces = '&nbsp; ';
  for(var i = 0;i<numSpaces;i++){
    allSpace += spaces;
  }
  return allSpace;
}

public getIcon(sizeDifference: number){
  return sizeDifference>0 ? {increaseIcon}:{decreaseIcon}
}
```

I did try doing it inline, and that seems to work.

```
return <span>{item.sizeDifference}&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<img src={item.sizeDifference>0?increaseIcon:decreaseIcon} alt="Increase" /></span>;
```

However, for more complex operations I would like to understand how I can use the value returned from a function.

Answer (score 0):

If we take this portion of your example:

```
var icon = this.getIcon(item.sizeDifference);
return <img src={this.getIcon(item.sizeDifference)} alt="Increase" />;
```

you would just do the following:

```
var icon = this.getIcon(item.sizeDifference);
return <img src={icon} alt="Increase" />;
```

Any place where it worked to call a method inline can be replaced by a variable set to that same result.